# List filter using an anamorphism

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, recursion-schemes, corecursion

I implemented a broken `filter` function using an anamorphism from `recursion-schemes` Hackage library:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

xfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
xfilter f = ana $ project . phi f

phi :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
phi f (h : t) | not (f h) = t
phi f l = l
```

The function is not a faithful implementation of `filter`: `xfilter odd [1..5]` works, but `xfilter odd [0,0]` doesn't. I tried to implement "retries" by using explicit recursion in `phi` and then reimplemented that with a paramorphism, so I ended with `ana . para`:

```
xfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
xfilter f = ana . para $ phi where
    phi Nil = Nil
    phi (Cons h (t, tt)) | f h = Cons h t
    phi (Cons h (t, tt)) = tt
```

This is satisfactory, but I then tried to express retries explicitly in `phi` and perform them outside:

```
xfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
xfilter f = ana $ project . retry (phi f)

phi :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Either [a] [a]
phi f (h : t) | not (f h) = Left t
phi f l = Right l

retry f x = case f x of
    Right x -> x
    Left x -> retry f x
```

`Right` means 'produce a new element' and `Left` means 'retry with a new seed'.

The signature of `phi` started to look pretty similar to the first argument of apomorphism specialized for lists:

```
xxapo :: ([a] -> Prim [a] (Either [a] [a])) -> [a] -> [a]
xxapo = apo
```

(`[a] -> Either [a] [a]` vs `[a] -> Prim [a] [a] (Either [a] [a]`)

So I wonder is it possible to implement filtering using apomorphisms or other generalized unfolds, or `ana . para` is the best I can hope for?

I know I can use folds, but the question is specifically about unfolds.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do that with anamorphism (or apomorphism) alone. These two schemes characterize productive corecursion and `filter` need not be productive: `filter (const False)`.

Comment: I can define `filter (const False)` using `ana (const Nil)`

Comment: Should your `filter` work on infinite lists?

Comment: I don't care for now.

Comment: btw, why do you need ana . para? you can do it with just para

Comment: I was pushing the limits of anamorphisms, for education sake.

Comment: @nponeccop ana- and apomorphisms are for coalgebras for some functor. Here we are dealing with list, so coalgebra must generate one element, and the seed for the rest, or a empty list. Since you need to skip zero or more elements in the seed list, your coalgebra is necessarily a paramorphism. In your case, this paramorphism implements a dropWhile (not.f)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: This can't be done. You always have to break down the input list somehow, which you can't accomplish by unfolding alone. You can see that in your code already. You have `retry (phi f)`, which is equivalent to `dropWhile (not . f)`, which recursively consumes an input list. In your case, the recursion is inside `retry`.

We can implement `filter` using `ana`, but the function passed to `ana` will have to be recursive, as in

```
filter1 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter1 p = ana f
  where
    f [] = Nil
    f (x : xs') | p x       = Cons x xs'
                | otherwise = f xs'
```

However, we can implement filtering using `para` without any further recursion:

```
filter2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter2 p = cata f
  where
    f Nil = []
    f (Cons x r) | p x          = x : r
                 | otherwise    = r
```

(although this is not what you've been interested in).

### So why it works with `cata` but not with `ana`?

- Catamorphisms represent inductive recursion where each recursive step consumes at least one constructor. Since each steps takes only finite time, together this ensures that when consuming a (finite) data structure, the whole recursion always terminates.
- Anamorphisms represent co-inductive recursion where each recursive step is guarded by a constructor. This means that although the result can be infinite, each part (a constructor) of the constructed data structure is produced in finite time.

Now how `filter` works: At each step it consumes one element of a list and sometimes it produces an output element (if it satisfies a given predicate).

So we see that we can implement `filter` as a catamorphism - we consume each element of a list in a finite time.

But we can't implement `filter` just as an anamorphism. We can never know when `filter` produces a new result. We can't describe the production of a next output element using just a finite number of operations. For example, let's take `filter odd (replicate n 0 ++ [1])` - it takes *O(n)* steps to produce the first element `1`. So there must be some kind of recursion that searches an input list until it finds a satisfying element.

Comment: Great explanation! "You always have to break down the input list" is a great argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
    xfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
    xfilter f xs = last $ apo phi ([xs], []) where
        phi ([[]], ys) = Cons [] $ Left [ys]
        phi ([h:t], ys) | f h = Cons [] $ Right ([t], h:ys)
        phi ([h:t], ys) = Cons [] $ Right ([t], ys)
```

But last is a cata.

Comment: Besides `last` being a cata, we end up doing all the list building through the seed, bypassing the element emission of the unfold. `xfilter`, as written here, will reverse the list, but that might be fixed with a dlist trick.

Comment: @duplode A trick to turn `filter` into a productive corecursion, which I saw in some paper on corecursion and (what else) the Sieve of Eratosthenes, is just to have each step produce a *list* of at most one element, and pass the overall result through a concat (moving the recursive onus onto *it*). `concat` is of course recursive as it can't know how many `[]` to skip over, but it's much *much* less off-line than `reverse . last` here. so, `afilter p = concat . ana phi where phi [] = Nil ; phi (x:xs) = Cons [x | p x] xs`, I guess.

Comment: @WillNess That's neat -- a hylo with a virtual list and `concat` (or `catMaybes`) on the fold side.

Comment: yes, `catMaybes` is much better -- and with MonadComprehensions, the code for `phi` even remains the same.