# Changing recursive guards into higher order functions

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to convert basic functions into higher order functions (specifically map, filter, or foldr). I was wondering if there are any simple concepts to apply where I could see old functions I've written using guards and turn them into higher order.

I'm working on changing a function called `filterFirst` that removes the first element from the list (second argument) that does not satisfy a given predicate function (first argument).

```
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst _ [] = []
filterFirst x (y:ys)
    | x y       = y : filterFirst x ys
    | otherwise = ys
```

For an example:

```
 greaterOne :: Num a=>Ord a=>a->Bool
 greaterOne x = x > 1

 filterFirst greaterOne [5,-6,-7,9,10]
 [5,-7,9,10]
```

Based on the basic recursion, I was wondering if there might be a way to translate this (and similar functions) to higher order map, filter, or foldr. I'm not very advanced and these functions are new to me.

Comment: Sounds like [`deleteBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:deleteBy): `deleteBy (>) 1 [5,-6,-7,9,10]`

Comment: Is the question, "can I express `filterFirst` in terms of `map`, `filter`, and/or `foldr`?"?

Comment: Yes. And once it's changed, I want to use it to help me understand replacing older, more basic functions with higher order functions. If someone could show me, or explain an easier way to translate it, I would be appreciative. I'm just learning how to use them.

Comment: You can write `filterFirst` (and essentially anything else) with `foldr`, but it will be rather inelegant. Using `mapAccumL` might provide a better result, but IMO explicit recursion is the best here.

Comment: @melpomene `deleteBy (>=)`, I think... this illustrates why passing non-symmetric functions to `deleteBy` is something I'd be cautious of.

Comment: @chi I think mapAccumL is unsuited because it is length-preserving (ie. you'd have to map it to something like `Maybe a` then take the `Just`s). Something like `concatMapAccum` from Data.Conduit.List could do it if it had a non-conduit analog (though that is more general, can send 1 element to any number of results).

Comment: @melpomene `deleteBy` would fit like a glove weren't it for its peculiar equivalence-expecting signature, which clashes with the general problem statement here. There actually have been calls to change `deleteBy` to `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`... but then, negated predicate aside, you end up with `filterFirst`, exactly as the OP presented it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we really want, we can write `filterFirst` using `foldr`, since `foldr` is kind of "universal" -- it allows any list transformation we can perform using recursion. The main downside is that the resulting code is rather counter-intuitive. In my opinion, explicit recursion is far better in this case.

Anyway here's how it is done. This relies on what I consider to be an antipattern, namely "passing *four* arguments to `foldr`". I call this an antipattern since `foldr` is usually called with three arguments only, and the result is not a function taking a fourth argument.

```
filterFirst :: (a->Bool)->[a]->[a]
filterFirst p xs = foldr go (\_ -> []) xs True
   where
   go y ys True 
      | p y = y : ys True 
      | otherwise = ys False
   go y ys False = y : ys False
```

Clear? Not very much. The trick here is to exploit `foldr` to build a function `Bool -> [a]` which returns the original list if called with `False`, and the filtered-first list if called with `True`. If we craft that function using

```
foldr go baseCase xs
```

the result is then obviously

```
foldr go baseCase xs True
```

Now, the base case must handle the empty list, and in such case we must return a function returning the empty list, whatever the boolean argument is. Hence, we arrive at

```
foldr go (\_ -> []) xs True
```

Now, we need to define `go`. This takes as arguments:

1. a list element `y`
2. the result of the "recursion" `ys` (a function `Bool->[a]` for the rest of the list)

and must return a function `Bool->[a]` for the larger list. So let's also consider

3. a boolean argument

and finally make `go` return a list. Well, if the boolean is `False` we must return the list unchanged, so

```
go y ys False = y : ys False
```

Note that `ys False` means "the tail unchanged", so we are really rebuilding the whole list unchanged.

If instead the boolean is true, we query the predicate as in `p y`. If that is false, we discard `y`, and return the list tail unchanged

```
   go y ys True 
      | p y = -- TODO
      | otherwise = ys False
```

If `p y` is true, we keep `y` and we return the list tail filtered.

```
   go y ys True 
      | p y = y : ys True
      | otherwise = ys False
```

As a final note, we cold have used a pair `([a], [a])` instead of a function `Bool -> [a]`, but that approach does not generalize as well to more complex cases.

So, that's all. This technique is something nice to know, but I do not recommend it in real code which is meant to be understood by others.

Comment: IMO, the main downside of a fold here is the loss of sharing. This is where paramorphisms come in.

Comment: (See my answer, and please feel free to edit it if you think you can help make it more accessible to Haskell beginners.)

Comment: An aside: I absolutely wouldn't consider higher-order use of `foldr` an anti-pattern. In some cases (not this one) it actually does produce clear code. In some cases (particularly when writing high-performance library code) it's necessary to take advantage of GHC's list fusion optimizations. And it's fairly often necessary when generalizing list-consuming functions to `Foldable`-consuming ones.

Comment: I find one aspect of this solution quite fun: In a foldr-with-four-arguments implementation, typically the fold operation either pre-composes functions (as in the foldl-from-foldr trick) or post-composes them (as in the dlist trick). Here it is necessary to do both, as we want to test the elements left-to-right without building a reversed list. That becomes plainer to the eye if we golf `go` into `go y ys = (bool id (y :) <*> ys) . (<= p y)` .

Comment: @dfeuer have you changed your [recent opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522847/implementing-haskells-take-function-using-foldl/55584633#comment97756176_55523947) or have I misunderstood it? what specifically had you objected to, there? what's your opinion about the sharing, paramorphism-equivalent  `filterFirst p xs = foldr go id xs xs where go x r ~(_:xs) | p x = x : r xs | otherwise = xs`? would it be good, fusion-wise? (meta clarification: I'm not being argumentative here; I want to understand your position). thanks.

Comment: (a variant: `... where go _ r (x:xs) | p x = ...`; might be clearer (?) )

Comment: @WillNess, I don't see any contradiction. What are you getting at? And I see no advantage whatsoever to using `foldr` if you're going to walk the list by pattern matching in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

There is a higher-order function that's appropriate here, but it's not in the base library. What's the trouble with `foldr`? If you just fold over the list, you'll end up rebuilding the whole thing, *including* the part after the deletion.

A more appropriate function for the job is [`para`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:para) from the `recursion-schemes` package (I've renamed one of the type variables):

```
para :: Recursive t => (Base t (t, r) -> r) -> t -> r
```

In the case of lists, this specializes to

```
para :: (ListF a ([a], r) -> r) -> [a] -> r
```

where

```
data ListF a b = Nil | Cons a b
  deriving (Functor, ....)
```

This is pretty similar to `foldr`. The `recursion-schemes` equivalent of `foldr` is

```
cata :: Recursive t => (Base t r -> r) -> t -> r
```

Which specializes to

```
cata :: (ListF a r -> r) -> [a] -> r
```

---

Take a break here and figure out why the type of `cata` is basically equivalent to that of `foldr`.

---

The difference between `cata` and `para` is that `para` passes the folding function not only the result of folding over the tail of the list, but also the tail of the list itself. That gives us an easy and efficient way to produce the rest of the list after we've found the first non-matching element:

```
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst f = para go
  where
    --go :: ListF a ([a], [a]) -> [a]
    go (Cons a (tl, r))
      | f a = a : r
      | otherwise = tl
    go Nil = []
```

---

`para` is a bit awkward for lists, since it's designed to fit into a more general context. But just as `cata` and `foldr` are basically equivalent, we could write a slightly less awkward function specifically for lists.

```
foldrWithTails
  :: (a -> [a] -> b -> b)
  -> b -> [a] -> b
foldrWithTails f n = go
  where
    go (a : as) = f a as (go as)
    go [] = n
```

Then

```
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst f = foldrWithTails go []
  where
    go a tl r
      | f a = a : r
      | otherwise = tl
```

Answer (score 3):

First, let's flip the argument order of your function. This will make a few steps easier, and we can flip it back when we're done. (I'll call the flipped version `filterFirst'`.)

```
filterFirst' :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
filterFirst' [] _ = []
filterFirst' (y:ys) x
    | x y       = y : filterFirst' ys x
    | otherwise = ys
```

Note that `filterFirst' ys (const True) = ys` for all `ys`. Let's substitute that in place:

```
filterFirst' :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
filterFirst' [] _ = []
filterFirst' (y:ys) x
    | x y       = y : filterFirst' ys x
    | otherwise = filterFirst' ys (const True)
```

Use if-else instead of a guard:

```
filterFirst' :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
filterFirst' [] _ = []
filterFirst' (y:ys) x = if x y then y : filterFirst' ys x else filterFirst' ys (const True)
```

Move the second argument to a lambda:

```
filterFirst' :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
filterFirst' [] = \_ -> []
filterFirst' (y:ys) = \x -> if x y then y : filterFirst' ys x else filterFirst' ys (const True)
```

And now this is something we can turn into a `foldr`. The pattern we were going for is that `filterFirst' (y:ys)` can be expressed in terms of `filterFirst' ys`, without using `ys` otherwise, and we're now there.

```
filterFirst' :: Foldable t => t a -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
filterFirst' = foldr (\y f -> \x -> if x y then y : f x else f (const True)) (\_ -> [])
```

Now we just need to neaten it up a bit:

```
filterFirst' :: Foldable t => t a -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
filterFirst' = foldr go (const [])
  where go y f x
          | x y       = y : f x
          | otherwise = f (const True)
```

And flip the arguments back:

```
filterFirst :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> [a]
filterFirst = flip $ foldr go (const [])
  where go y f x
          | x y       = y : f x
          | otherwise = f (const True)
```

And we're done. `filterFirst` implemented in terms of `foldr`.

---

Addendum: Although `filter` isn't strong enough to build this, `filterM` is when used with the State monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.State

filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst x ys = evalState (filterM go ys) False
  where go y = do
          alreadyDropped <- get
          if alreadyDropped || x y then
            return True
          else do
            put True
            return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Joseph and chi's answers already show how to derive a `foldr` implementation, so I'll try to aid intuition.

`map` is length-preserving, `filterFirst` is not, so trivially `map` must be unsuited for implementing `filterFirst`.

`filter` (and indeed `map`) are memoryless - the same predicate/function is applied to each element of the list, regardless of the result on other elements. In `filterFirst`, behaviour changes once we see the first non-satisfactory element and remove it, so `filter` (and `map`) are unsuited.

`foldr` is used to reduce a structure to a summary value. It's very general, and it might not be immediately obvious without experience what sorts of things this may cover. `filterFirst` is in fact such an operation, though. The intuition is something like, "can we build it in a single pass through the structure, building it up as we go(, with additional state stored as required)?". I fear Joseph's answer obfuscates a little, as `foldr` with 4 parameters, it may not be immediately obvious what's going on, so let's try it a little differently.

```
filterFirst p xs = snd $ foldr (\a (deleted,acc) -> if not deleted && not (p a) then (True,acc) else (deleted,a:acc) ) (False,[]) xs
```

Here's a first attempt. The "extra state" here is obviously the bool indicating whether or not we've deleted an element yet, and the list accumulates in the second element of the tuple. At the end we call `snd` to obtain just the list. This implementation has the problem, however, that we delete the *rightmost* element not satisfying the predicate, because `foldr` first combines the rightmost element with the neutral element, then the second-rightmost, and so on.

```
filterFirst p xs = snd $ foldl (\(deleted,acc) a -> if not deleted && not (p a) then (True,acc) else (deleted,a:acc) ) (False,[]) xs
```

Here, we try using `foldl`. This does delete the leftmost non-satisfactory element, but has the side-effect of reversing the list. We can stick a `reverse` at the front, and this would solve the problem, but is somewhat unsatisfactory due to the double-traversal.

Then, if you go back to `foldr`, having realized that (basically) if you want transform a list whilst preserving order that `foldr` is the correct variant, you play with it for a while and end up writing what Joseph suggested. I do however agree with chi that straightforward recursion is the best solution here.

Comment: [map + zip = scanl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951590/849891) and we can do a lot with scanl.

Comment: @WillNess lol I'm not sure how I feel about that link, but I stand by the claim that `map` is *unsuited* to the task, if not *unusable*.

Comment: my lesson from it was, that in Haskell, `[] a` is not an unordered collection of `a`s, and `zip` is just `map2 (,)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function can also be expressed as an unfold, or, more specifically, as an apomorphism. Allow me to begin with a brief explanatory note, before the solution itself.

---

The apomorphism is the recursion scheme dual to the paramorphism (see [dfeuer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926036/2751851) for more about the latter). Apomorphisms are examples of unfolds, which generate a structure from a seed. For instance, `Data.List` offers `unfoldr`, a list unfold.

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

The function given to `unfoldr` takes a seed and either produces a list element and a new seed (if the maybe-value is a `Just`) or terminates the list generation (if it is `Nothing`). Unfolds are more generally expressed by the `ana` function from *recursion-schemes* ("ana" is short for "anamorphism").

```
ana :: Corecursive t => (a -> Base t a) -> a -> t
```

Specialised to lists, this becomes...

```
ana @[_] :: (b -> ListF a b) -> b -> [a]
```

... which is `unfoldr` in different clothing.

An apomorphism is an unfold in which the generation of the structure can be short-circuited at any point of the process, by producing, instead of a new seed, the rest of the structure in a fell swoop. In the case of lists, we have:

```
apo @[_] :: (b -> ListF a (Either [a] b)) -> b -> [a]
```

`Either` is used to trigger the short-circuit: with a `Left` result, the unfold short-circuits, while with a `Right` it proceeds normally.

---

The solution in terms of `apo` is fairly direct:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable

filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst p = apo go
  where
  go = \case
    [] -> Nil
    a : as
      | p a -> Cons a (Right as) 
      | otherwise -> case as of
        [] -> Nil
        b : bs -> Cons b (Left bs)
```

It is somewhat more awkward than dfeuer's `para`-based solution, because if we want to short-circuit without an empty list for a tail we are compelled to emit one extra element (the `b` in the short-circuiting case), and so we have to look one position ahead. This awkwardness would grow by orders of magnitude if, rather than `filterFirst`, we were to impĺement plain old `filter` with an unfold, as beautifully explained in [*List filter using an anamorphism*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18421926/2751851).

Comment: Your presentation is much better than mine. I may have to borrow some of it if I have time to revise.

Comment: @dfeuer I, in turn, have borrowed your `foldrWithTails` [for an answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032831/2751851).

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is inspired by [a comment from luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940787/filterfirst-in-haskell-using-higher-order-functions#comment98535277_55940787) on a now-deleted question.*

`filterFirst` can be implemented in a fairly direct way in terms of [`span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span):

```
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst p = (\(yeas, rest) -> yeas ++ drop 1 rest) . span p
```

`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` splits the list in two at the first element for which the condition doesn't hold. After `span`, we drop the first element of the second part of the list (with `drop 1` rather than `tail` so that we don't have to add a special case for `[]`), and reassemble the list with `(++)`.

As an aside, there is a near-pointfree spelling of this implementation which I find too pretty not to mention:

```
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterFirst p = uncurry (++) . second (drop 1) . span p
```

---

While `span` is a higher order function, it would be perfectly understandable if you found this implementation disappointing in the context of your question. After all, `span` is not much more fundamental than `filterFirst` itself. Shouldn't we try going a little deeper, to see if we can capture the spirit of this solution while expressing it as a fold, or as some other recursion scheme?

I believe functions like `filterFirst` can be fine demonstrations of *hylomorphisms*. A hylomorphism is an unfold (see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929279/2751851) for more on that) that generates an intermediate data structure followed by a fold which turns this data structure into something else. Though it might look like that would require two passes to get a result (one through the input structure, and another through the intermediate one), if the hylomorphism implemented properly (as done in the `hylo` function of *recursion-schemes*) it can be done in a single pass, with the fold consuming pieces of the intermediate structure as they are generated by the unfold (so that we don't have to actually build it all only to tear it down).

Before we start, here is the boilerplate needed to run what follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH
```

The strategy here is picking an intermediate data structure for the hylomorphism that expresses the essence of what we want to achieve. In this case, we will use this cute thing:

```
data BrokenList a = Broken [a] | Unbroken a (BrokenList a)
    -- I won't actually use those instances here,
    -- but they are nice to have if you want to play with the type.
    deriving (Eq, Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
makeBaseFunctor ''BrokenList
```

`BrokenList` is very much like a list (`Broken` and `Unbroken` mirror `[]` and `(:)`, while the `makeBaseFunctor` incantation generates a `BrokenListF` base functor analogous to `ListF`, with `BrokenF` and `UnbrokenF` constructors), except that it has another list attached at its end (the `Broken` constructor). It expresses, in a quite literal way, the idea of a list being divided in two parts.

With `BrokenList` at hand, we can write the hylomorphism. `coalgSpan` is the operation used for the unfold, and `algWeld`, the one used for the fold.

```
filterFirst p = hylo algWeld coalgSpan
    where
    coalgSpan = \case
        [] -> BrokenF []
        x : xs
            | p x -> UnbrokenF x xs
            | otherwise -> BrokenF xs
    algWeld = \case
        UnbrokenF x yeas -> x : yeas
        BrokenF rest -> rest
```

`coalgSpan` breaks the list upon hitting a `x` element such that `p x` doesn't hold. Not adding that element to the second part of the list (`BrokenF xs` rather than `BrokenF (x : xs)`) takes care of the filtering. As for `algWeld`, it is used to concatenate the two parts (it is very much like what we would use to implement `(++)` using `cata`).

(For a similar example of `BrokenList` in action, see the `breakOn` implementation in Note 5 of [this older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271176/2751851). It suggests what it would take to implement `span` using this strategy.)

There are at least two good things about this `hylo`-based implementation. Firstly, it has good performance (casual testing suggests that, if compiled with optimisations, it is at least as good as, and possibly slightly faster than, the most efficient implementations in other answers here). Secondly, it reflects very closely your original, explicitly recursive implementation of `filterFirst` (or, at any rate, more closely than the fold-only and unfold-only implementations).

Comment: `BrokenList` is ["`People`"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#Implicit_Heap) too. :)

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, that is very interesting! Though I had tried to find prior art on `BrokenList`, this particular search string would never have occurred to me :)

Comment: [here's where it started](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-July/029391.html).

Comment: I think it would pay to motivate the use of `hylo` by showing the unfused production and consumption of a `BrokenList`. It would also be nice to explain how using `BrokenList` is better (Easier to understand? Easier to modify somehow?) than a direct approach using `para` or raw pattern matching.

Comment: @dfeuer I'll look into doing that. As for what is better, the `para` solution is also fine, and explicit recursion isn't actually hard to follow in this specific case. Still, in spite of the relative verbosity I find the `hylo` solution very transparent. Maybe it's just an aesthetic feeling, but I find it very satisfying to see a datatype capturing an essential aspect of an algorithm like that. ([Designer monoid `foldMap` solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55816153/2751851) make me happy in a similar way.)